# Music not playing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, switch-statement

I am having some issues with my code. I am generating a random number from 1 to 4 and playing a music based on the number generated. why is this code not working?

```
var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
switch(random){
    case 1:
        var audio1=new Audio('green.mp3');
        audio1.play();
        break;
    case 2:
        var audio2=new Audio('red.mp3');
        audio2.play();
        break;
    case 3:
        var audio3=new Audio('yellow.mp3');
        audio3.play();
        break;
    case 4:
        var audio4=new Audio('blue.mp3');
        audio4.play();
        break;
    
    default:
        break;
}
```

When I do an "addEventListener" to check for a keypress and play a music, the code seems to work fine, so I am certain the music files are linked properly. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

to play music you need action from users

then browser will play sounds

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to play audio on page load, you can use an [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element with the `autoplay` tag. Note that [not all browsers allow autoplaying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide) because some users find it annoying.

```js
let audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.autoplay = true;
audio.src = "path/to/audio";
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

```css
html {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>Replace path/to/audio in the script with your desired path.</p>
```